# How to do soap call using javascript or jquery. I am getting 405 error on executing my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a soap call. And when I am calling this i am getting 405 error. Can anyone solve this .. that will be really helpful ,I am very new to soap call. 
Please do help me and don't mark this question as duplicate, i checked that too .. no use

```
POST /axis/services/G2A_PhoneMode HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 609
User-Agent: Crosscheck Networks SOAPSonar
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns0="G2A_Sessions">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <tns0:logon>
            <loginId xsi:type="xsd:string">user@company.com</loginId>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string">somePassword</password>
            <version xsi:type="xsd:long">1</version>
        </tns0:logon>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```js
function logOnAgent() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://broker.gotoassist.com/axis/services/G2A_PhoneMode', true);
  var xml_string = '<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
                        + '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns0="G2A_Sessions">'
                        + '<soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'
                        + '<tns0:logon>'
                        + '<loginId xsi:type="xsd:string">myusername@nanoheal.com</loginId>'
                        + '<password xsi:type="xsd:string">myPassword</password>'
                        + '<version xsi:type="xsd:long">1</version>'
                        + '</tns0:logon>'
                        + '</soap:Body>'
                        + '</soap:Envelope>';
  
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
  xmlhttp.send(xml_string);
  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}

logOnAgent();
```

Comment: you didn't get any proper answer for your question ? then let us know. or Approve answer if you got solution .

Answer (score 0):

@Shubham, please try this:-

```
    var aux = document.createElement("textarea");
    aux.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
    aux.value = "this\nis\na\nstring";
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
```

This will work. Actually the "opacity:0;" is the cause here. Just remove it from your style attribute and it will work perfectly.

Comment: yeah it is getting inside the textarea tag in multiple lines ,but when i'm copying it ,it is coming in single line.

Comment: `document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(aux);`

Answer (score 0):

For showing text in multiple line in TextArea you need to use \r\n and it will put insert into textarea, check the example. I used Jquery, you can also use javascript same as I done.

```js
$("#a").html("hello\r\ntest\r\nthis")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
```